# How to get table and update SQL Server data from Xcode using webservices?

Tags: iphone, web-services

I am new to Xcode programming. I need a solution for to connect SQL Server from iPhone and I have to perform select,insert and update operations from app.

Any one please give me any idea or sample example for this?

Comment: You mention web-services in your question, but in response to answers showing how to talk to web-services you talk about connecting directly to the database with IP and port number (which is a bad idea). Unless you're running something like the SQL Server HTTP stack (which is a bad idea to expose to the world) you can't connect directly to your database using url requests.

Comment: My actual requirement is to get all tables data from xx.database.which is in server.and up date values in table view.please tell me the correct process and can i update data base of remote server from my app?if possible let me know the way please.

Comment: You need an in-between layer where you put the code that talks to the database in a safe way, thus the suggestions for a web service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need web services to achieve what you need. Here are two great tutorial to start with that:

- [How To Write A Simple PHP/MySQL Web Service for an iOS App?](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app)
- [How to Write an iOS App That Uses a Web Service?](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2965/how-to-write-an-ios-app-that-uses-a-web-service)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I have the database port number,user id,password and ip address.now can i get the table from the data base in that ip address with login credentials.please give sample code for connecting using urlrequest.......Thanks in advance